# VS Code warning

Tags: powershell, visual-studio-code

I have this warning which I cannot resolve . I am a newbie in VS Code and Python, hence I appreciate any steps  are explained as simple as possible.

---

> : File C:\Users\xxxxx\Documents\WindowsPowerShell\profile.ps1
>   cannot be loaded because running scripts is disabled on  this system.
>   For more information, see about_Execution_Policies at
>   https:/go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkID=135170. At line:1 char:3
>   + . 'C:\Users\xxxxx\Documents\WindowsPowerShell\profile.ps1'
>   +   ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
>       + CategoryInfo          : SecurityError: (:) [], PSSecurityException
>       + FullyQualifiedErrorId : UnauthorizedAccess

I have also run the following Execution Policy -List (see below):

---

I have also run Windows Powershell ISE
I have also run et-ExecutionPolicy -List and below is what I have

> (base) PS C:\Windows\system32> Get-ExecutionPolicy -List
>
> ```
>     Scope ExecutionPolicy
>     ----- --------------- MachinePolicy       Undefined    UserPolicy       Undefined
>   Process       Undefined   CurrentUser    Unrestricted  LocalMachine    RemoteSigned
> ```
>
> (base) PS C:\Windows\system32

---

I appreciate some help to resolve this pls. Thank you.

Comment: take a look at this -> https://superuser.com/questions/106360/how-to-enable-execution-of-powershell-scripts

Comment: Hi ,I have already done settings to currentUser Unrestricted as you can see in my post above.

Comment: how are you running the python script ?